# Switching Freq. and Output voltage error

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, gate-driving

[image]
Attached is the datasheet for the Synchronous Buck Controller: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvsb32b/snvsb32b.pdf?ts=1711536038118&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FLM5145EVM-HD-20A

EVM module datasheet from the schematic of which I have taken the data for simulation : https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu545a/snvu545a.pdf?ts=1711465253414&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FLM5145EVM-HD-20A

I am simulating this circuit in LTspice for Vin1= 30V to get output 5V but it is coming around 5.4V. Secondly I have set Rrt as 46.4k which should give me Fsw ~ 215kHz (acc. to datasheet formula) but it is operating at 152kHz. What's going wrong in the simulation?

Waveforms at steady state:

1st waveform Vds of U2.
2nd waveform Vds of U1.
3rd waveform Voutput.
4th waveform Inductor current.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the LTspice model from?

Comment: @RohatKılıç SIMULATION MODEL
LM5145 PSpice Unencrypted Transient Model from TI website

Comment: What's R10 all about? What supply in?

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu545a/snvu545a.pdf?ts=1711465253414&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FLM5145EVM-HD-20A

replicated from the schematic here @Andyaka

Comment: That schematic needs to be part of your question.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, I have edited.

Comment: I've also edited your simulation circuit to make it more legible on screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmQBq.png

Comment: @Andyaka Can you comment on why the switching frequency is varying this much in the simulation?

Comment: @Andr7 I can't see any circuit differences so, it just leaves the reliability of the model and, I am unable to comment on that.